# Tint color for ios12 system image button doesn't work

Tags: swift, ios13, imagebutton, ios12, tintcolor

I set the tintcolor of two system image buttons via storyboard, it works perfectly in all simulators and with ios13. but if I try with real Iphone 5s with ios 12.4 the two buttons are not displayed, the only things that properly works is button background color. I tried programmaticaly with `plusBtn.imageView?.tintColor = .yellow` or `plusBtn.tintColor = .yellow`. but it's the same,it works with ios13 but not with iphone 5s.

This is iphone 11 Pro simulator:
[image]

and this is my real iphone5s device:

[image]

How can I set image tint color?

Comment: +1  Also reproduced the same - filled UIImage also loses color info with rendering mode = .alwaysOriginal. Since they come empty, not possible to set tint (template or original mode - doesn't matter.) iOS 11 device, same buggy result. Works OK with iOS 13. If you found any workaround, please post.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `.withRenderingMode` property to `.alwaysTemplate` for `tintColor` to work.

```
plusBtn.imageView?.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

Comment: Do this after you set the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the image programmatically but **you have to remove it** from Attributes inspector in storyboard :) it solved the bug in iOS 12